# How are UML model relationships coded in C++?

Tags: c++

This question is in my exam revision, and I'm wondering if I'm on the right track with it, It is from the C++ primer text book.

**How are UML model relationships coded in C++?**

Public inheritance allows you to model IS-A relationships, with derived classes being able to reuse code of base classes. Another approach is to use containment, which is the relationship between objects where one object owns or has the other object. This models HAS-A relationships.

For example:

- Car has or owns Motor
- When Car is built, it's motor is also built
- When Car is destroyed, its motor is also destroyed.

  ```
  class Car 
  {
      private:
          Motor *motor;
      public:
          Car()
          { 
               motor = new Motor(); 
          }

          ~Car() 
          { 
               delete motor; 
          }
  };
  ```

Comment: C++ is not Java, there is no need to dynamically allocate a Motor in your example.

Answer (score 3):

With C++ it's easier to build composition relations than with Java. In the simplest case, the contained object is just a value member:

```
class Car {
private:
  Motor motor;
  // No explicit construction/destruction required
};
```

It gets more complicated when you want to contain an `AbstractMotor` whose dynamic type is determined by the caller using dependency injection. To model composition in this case, you can use `unique_ptr`:

```
class Car {
public:
  explicit Car(std::unique_ptr<AbstractMotor> motor): motor(std::move(motor)) { }
private:
  std::unique_ptr<AbstractMotor> motor;  // Still no explicit destruction required
};
```

`unique_ptr` ensures that your `Car` is the unique owner of the `Motor`, and that `Motor`'s lifetime is bound to the `Car` object.

Try to avoid using raw pointers when an objects owns another object. With `unique_ptr`, it shouldn't be necessary to implement nontrivial destructors or use the `delete` operator at all.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't add much to your answer.

As far as IS-A relationship is concerned, **public** inheritance of is the tool in C++ (it gets tricky when using templates though and not always works as expected). When it comes to HAS-A relationship then class members are the solution. To be really precise, I'd use a `Motor motor` member (not a pointer), since this even more strongly emphasizes the relation between the two. And as far as pointer can be `null`, a member will always be constructed and destroyed.

HTH,
elmes

Answer (score 0):

> Public inheritance allows you to model IS-A relationships, with derived classes being able to reuse code of base classes.

That is a common misconception. The point of inheritance is not being able to reuse code **of** base classes, but rather leverage existing code that handles the base type providing different behaviors. That is, at least in OO theory.

C++ is a powerful flexible language, and there is no single mapping of UML to the language (this is where those expecting code generation from UML will fail once and again, UML does not capture some of the fine grained details).

**Generalization** and **Realization** are both implemented through inheritance<sup>0</sup> in C++, although in other languages they differ. As an example, in Java *generalization* is implemented through inheritance (`extends`) and *realization* through interface implementation (`implements`).

**Composition** this is the *has-a* relationship and is commonly implemented through *value members* of a class. Note that this is not the only implementation<sup>1</sup>.

**Aggregation** can be implemented through pointer<sup>2</sup> and reference members, depending on other criteria including the relative lifetimes of the two objects and whether the reference can be reset to a different object.

**Use** is not explicitly modeled, but rather *happens*. The *use* relationship can be present in the interface (a function that takes or returns an object of a different type *uses* that type), or the implementation (a function that in its definition uses a different type --instantiates an object of that type for some purpose) also uses the type. Some people consider these two as different variants of *use*, with the first one being more strict than the second, as it adds a tighter coupling from the *used* type to external code that *uses* your type itself.

Finally, with templates there are multiple other options. For example, there is no relationship between `std::vector<>::iterator` and `std::deque<>::iterator` in the language, but they model the concept of *RandomAccessIterator* in the language, and a template that was designed to work with a *RandomAccessIterator* can use both of them (for example, `std::sort`) From the point of view of `std::sort` both *are* random access iterators, the relationship is **Generalization** of that concept, although that is not present in the code at all (it will be if they finally end up adding some flavor of *concepts* to the language).

---

<sup>0)</sup> In general, we would be talking only of *public inheritance*, but that need not be the case. A type that inherits publicly from a different type is obviously *generalizing*/*realizing* another type/interface, but that can also happen through private inheritance. One thing that is not commonly presented when teaching OO is that a class has **two** separate interfaces. On the one side there is a *public* interface through which users of your type interact with your object. On the other side there is a *virtual* interface, that is the contract between your type and other types that extend your behavior. A common idiom in C++ is the NVI Non-virtual interface, that tries to exploit this by forcing a separation: no public virtual functions imply that the public and virtual interfaces are completely isolated.  In the same way, a type T might not have a *public is-a* relationship with a base, although internally it can pass references or pointers to the base type to other subsystems. For those subsystems the type T *is-a* base. Protected inheritance can be ignored as it is considered useless with no motivating usage example.

<sup>1)</sup> In some cases, driven by other needs, it can be implemented with members of pointer type, as long as they are allocated on construction and released on destruction of the enclosing type. In some cases inheritance is *abused* to do *composition* and perform size optimizations (empty base optimization). For example, instead of holding a comparator, a `std::map` can inherit from the comparator (using SFINAE to detect when the comparator is a functor). If the type of the comparator has no state which is quite frequent, the compiler can place the comparator and the first member of the `std::map` in the same memory location (i.e. the comparator will not take any space).

<sup>2)</sup> Consider the term *pointer* in a general sense that includes smart pointers.